# JSF update component on every ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf, message

Hi i want to render the JSF messages as bootstrap alerts

```
<ui:repeat value="#{facesContext.messageList}" var="facesMessage">
    <div class="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> #{facesMessage.summary}
    </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

in primefaces there is

```
<p:messages autoUpdate=true>
```

means it is rerendered on every ajax request without explicit adding it to the render-attribute of a commandLink

is there a way to achieve this with plain JSF-ajax tags?

Comment: No, there isn't. You must manually add a `<f:ajax render="yourFacesMessagesComponentId" />` on every `<h:commandButton>`. That's why for these cases is recommended to use a third party library.

Comment: can primefaces do this?

Comment: `<p:messages autoUpdate=true>`?

Comment: hm with this i can't design a bootstrap-alert

Comment: @BalusC what's your take on this, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try something like this during your page load:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(autoRender);
```

And in `autoRender` you would be able to trigger a kind of action in order to render the target component. For instance:

```
function autoRender() {
    $(":form:autoRenderHiddenButton").click();
}
```

And in the button:

```
<h:commandButton id="autoRenderHiddenButton" 
                 style="display: none">

    <f:ajax render="theComponentIdYouWantToRender"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Or you can easily achieve the same behavior by using [Omniface's commandScript](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript):

```html
<o:commandScript name="autoRender" render="theComponentIdYouWantToRender"/>
```